# Jmeter parameterization for content of the file uploaded

Tags: jmeter, parameterization

I'm trying to parameterize content of the file uploaded through CSV Data Set Config 
But file not picking the variables values ( can see the data of csv file in request but the uploaded file not updated with the number) Showing the request like this

```
**
POST data:
--3TJ-KduX0_gdJ3BvxwP97-p3PBN0Jki-2P7Iyvd
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="SO"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

403331689
--3TJ-KduX0_gdJ3BvxwP97-p3PBN0Jki-2P7Iyvd
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sourceFile"; filename="SO_perf_test_porfornmance.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

**
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending the file via "Files Upload" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler like this:

[image]

JMeter doesn't evaluate any [Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which are inside the file, it sends the file "as it is".

One of the solutions would be using a temporary file like `SO_perf_test_porfornmance_modified.xml` in the HTTP Request sampler and the content of this file can be modified "on-the-fly" using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) like:

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler which uploads tile
2. Put the following expression into "Parameters" section:

   ```
   ${__eval(${__FileToString(SO_perf_test_porfornmance.xml,,)})}
   ```

   where:

   - __FileToString() function reads the content of the `SO_perf_test_porfornmance.xml` into memory
   - __eval() function resolves all the functions and variables in it

     Check out [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables/) article if you need more detailed explanation.
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   new File('SO_perf_test_porfornmance_modified.xml').text = Parameters
   ```
4. Configure your HTTP Request sampler to send `SO_perf_test_porfornmance_modified.xml` file instead of the `SO_perf_test_porfornmance.xml`

   [image]
5. That's it, JMeter will now be sending the new file which contains all the nested functions and/or variables resolved to their respective values